# Propper initialization of an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have always initialized my ArrayLists like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

But according to my IDE, the part after `new ArrayList<>` should be empty like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @L01c: Not really, there's a difference between `= new ArrayList<>()` and `= new ArrayList()` (what that question asks about).

Comment: Updated the question @L01c

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The question doesn't ask about `= new ArrayList()`. (well the edit contains that now, because OP blindly copied your comment)

Comment: @Tom: *"However in Java 5/6, I can simply write: `List<String> list = new LinkedList();`"*

Comment: The question thought <Integer> was a html element so it dissapeared. Edited to make it visible again

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And where is this quote from? Not from the question at least.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, it's from the question that L01c linked. Isn't that what you were talking about?

Comment: It is from what he thinks this question is a duplicate of

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah you quoted the refered question, not this one here. The misunderstanding was on my side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are correct and they do exactly the same thing. The second way got introduced in Java7. It's called the ["diamond operator."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)

> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.

Comment: Why is it like that?

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Because you need not to write your type twice.

Comment: @Polarbear0106 because if you've got a complex type list `List<Map<Map<String, Collection<?>>, Map<String, Collection<?>>>`, it causes you eyes and brain enough pain to see it just once, never mind twice. (Not that I would recommend having such an unreadable type in the first place, however).

Answer (score 1):

Second one is known as Type Inference. If the compiler is able to infer the type argument from the context, then you can use empty set of type parameters while invoking your constructor

Even the first one is correct, but with second one, you have to write a bit less code.

For more info : [Generics Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)